# Google map nearbySearch Incorrect number of records

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I executed [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=6.9119022,79.8553512&radius=5000&type=atm&key=<key>) request for 5000m radius, I could obtain 60 records, when using `next_page_token` for subsequent requests.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=&key=

But when I executed request with radius=50000, I could obtain only 38 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nature of the Places API web service. It doesn't work as a database search and doesn't return all possible results. It returns only most prominent results for specified area. How Google decides which result is prominent and which is not we don't know, they typically don't share their internal algorithms.